# An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first

I'm trying to call a method from IActionResult using Task.Run. This is the Exception I am getting.

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code:
>   'An exception was thrown while attempting to evaluate a LINQ query
>   parameter expression. To show additional information call
>   EnableSensitiveDataLogging() when overriding DbContext.OnConfiguring.'
>   Inner exceptions found, see $exception in variables window for more
>   details.  Innermost exception      System.NullReferenceException : Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object.

Initialization of EntityContext instance:

```
private readonly EntityContext _context; 
public ApiController (
  UserManager<User> userManager,
  SignInManager<User> signInManager,
  ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
  IMemoryCache memoryCache,
  EntityContext context,
  IRepository repository,
  Context session,
  IEmailService emailService,
  IHostingEnvironment environment,
  IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, ViewRender view, IStringLocalizer<SharedResources> localizer) : base (userManager, signInManager, loggerFactory, memoryCache, context, repository, session, contextAccessor) {
  //_view = view;
  _emailService = emailService;
  this.environment = environment;
  _localizer = localizer;
  this._context = context;


}
```

Startup.cs

```
 services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql ()
    .AddDbContext<EntityContext> (
      options => options.UseNpgsql (connectionString)
    );
```

Calling method from controller:

```
if(updated){
      Task t1 = Task.Run(()=>SendEmailAsync(entity,true,responsible,_context));
    }else{
      Task t1 = Task.Run(()=>SendEmailAsync(entity,false,responsible,_context));
    }
```

Method I am calling:

```
public void SendEmailAsync (Activity entity, bool updated, User responsible, EntityContext ctx) {

  List<string> emailList = new List<string> ();

  var mail = new MailComposer (_emailService, environment, _localizer);

  if (responsible.IsSubscriber) {
    emailList.Add (responsible.Email);
  }
  if (entity.Participants.Count > 0) {
    foreach (var item in entity.Participants) {
      var p = ctx.Users.Where(c=>c.Id==item.Participant.Id).FirstOrDefault(); //This is where I am getting an exception.
      if (p.IsSubscriber) {
        emailList.Add (p.Email);
      }

    }
  }
  if (emailList.Count != 0) {
    var emailArray = emailList.ToArray ();
    if (updated) {
      mail.SendActivityUpdate (entity, emailArray);
    } else {
      mail.SendActivityCreated (entity, emailArray);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your issue, this is caused by that you are reference a scoped service `EntityContext` from another thread. For `EntityContext`, it will be disposed when the request returned  from Controller.

As the suggestion from Chris, you may call `t1.Wait();` to complete the t1 task before the request return back to client. By calling `t1.Wait();`, the `EntityContext _context` will not be disposed and then you won't get any error.

For another option, you may try pass `IServiceProvider` to create a new `EntityContext` instead of referencing the existing `EntityContext` which is created by `Controller`

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{        
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;        
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context            
        , IServiceProvider serviceProvider
        , ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _context = context;            
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public IActionResult TestTask()
    {
        Task t1 = Task.Run(() => SendEmailAsync(_serviceProvider));
        //t1.Wait();
        return Ok();
    }
    private void SendEmailAsync(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {            
        var context = _serviceProvider.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        var result = context.Student.ToList();
        _logger.LogInformation(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Task.Run` will start a new thread, and unless you await it, the existing thread where the action is running will keep going, eventually returning and taking the context with it, which your method running in the new thread depends on. If you *do* await it, then there's no point in running in a separate thread; you're just consuming additional resources for no good reason.

In short, you should not be using `Task.Run` for this at all. It's not the same as "running the background". Instead, you should schedule the email to be sent on different process or at the very least an `IHostedService`. You can use `QueuedBackgroundService`. There's an implementation available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks.